# Wikimedia Commons API: search for Commons categories near a location

Tags: geolocation, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api, wikimedia-commons

After reading [Wikimedia Commons API search images by (latitude, longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990161/wikimedia-commons-api-search-images-by-latitude-longitude), I know that we can find **pages** around a specified location using the MediaWiki API with the GeoData extension. However, I am looking to obtain **Commons categories** around a specified location via that API - is that doable?

I am also aware that WikiData API does this (as stated at [API to get Wikimedia Commons categories that are near a particular latitude/longitude](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/api-to-get-wikimedia-commons-categories-that-are-near-a-particular-latitude-long)). I have already used that, and am looking for a different API so that I can perform a comparison between the results of the two if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "categories around a specified location"? Categories rarely have coordinates. It's technically possible to do a geosearch over categories (use the `gsnamespace` parameter) but unlikely to produce useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is moot because Commons has precisely zero categories with geotags** (and why would it? how can a category have coordinates?), however the general solution is to filter by category namespace, 14 (full list of namespaces is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&formatversion=2)). So you take the query from the question you mentioned and modify it with `gsnamespace=14`:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsprimary=all&gsnamespace=14&gsradius=10000&gscoord=51.5|11.95

You might also want to try looking for galleries in mainspace (`gsnamespace=0`), maybe there is anything that could interest you.