# How do I get a list of wikicommon images around a given gps location?

Tags: wikipedia-api

How do I get a list of wikicommon images around a given gps location?

Here there is the wikipedia API:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

But I don't see how to specify a coordinates of an image.

Comment: Use `action=query&list=geosearch` in the Commons API.

Comment: thx. i found this page using your info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990161/wikimedia-commons-api-search-images-by-latitude-longitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wikimedia Commons API search images by (latitude, longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990161/wikimedia-commons-api-search-images-by-latitude-longitude)